# How can I print out multiple similar patterns I have matched in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, bioinformatics, protein-database

So I got a uniprot flat file in fasta format (https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P30988.txt here is the link but it's supposed to be able to work with any uniprot flat file) and I want to essentially take the transmembrane parts from the sequence and print them out. Here is what I have done so far:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
open (IN,'P30988.txt');
while (<IN>) {
    if($_=~ m/^ID/) {
    print $_ ; }
    if($_=~ m/^AC/){
    print $_ ; }
    #if ($_=~ m/^SQ/){
    #print $_; }
    if ($_=~ m/^\s+(.+)/) {
    $seq.=$1;                   # Here I match ONLY the sequence
    $seq=~s/\s//g; print $seq;  # Here I removed spaces from the sequence
     }

    if($_=~ m/^FT\s+TRANSMEM\s+(\d+)\.\.(\d+)/){
    $s=$1; $e=$2;} # Now I know that
      # this is the way to match the lines that mention the
      # transmembrane parts and the parentheses are the number of
      # the amino acids on the sequence BUT as it has multiple
      # transmembrane domains I am not very sure how to handle it.

    $tr=substr ($seq, $s-1, $e-$s+1); # here I try to use the numbers
      # given in the file to get the sequences of each part

    push (@transmembrane, $tr);
    print @transmembrane; # Now this is something I tried and while
    # it printed a sequence it was not the same length as the total
    # amount of amino acids that are in the transmembrane parts. Not
    # sure whats up with that.
```

The issue I have is that I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that `$1` and `$2` are not one value but as many as there are transmembrane parts.

If any of you know how to make this work I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, but for multiple matches, one usually uses `while(/^FT\s+TRANSMEM\s+(\d+)\.\.(\d+)/g) { ... }` instead of `if`. Note the `/g` to remember where the previous match ended.

Comment: To try and explain it again, I need to get the transmembrane parts of the sequence and print them separately I used pattern matching to get the positions of the lengths in the sequence but I cant seem to be able to print them out separately. Also could you explain what difference does while make instead of if in this case?

Comment: I have no idea what a transmembrane is. Can you probably show what output you get from the sample input and what output you expect instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ As with @choroba I have no idea what a transmembrane is, so I'm guessing in the code below ]

First thing - you script doesn't compile - you are missing the closing `}` for the `while` block.

Next observation is in this block of code (I've removed your comments and reformatted make the code clearer)

```
    if($_=~ m/^FT\s+TRANSMEM\s+(\d+)\.\.(\d+)/){  
        $s=$1; 
        $e=$2;
    } 
    $tr=substr ($seq, $s-1, $e-$s+1); 
    push (@transmembrane, $tr); 
    print @transmembrane;
```

I'm guessing that you want the `$tr` variable updated every time that the regex matches and added to `@transmembrane`. Unfortunately, these two lines are not in the scope of the `if` statement, so it will only happen once.

```
    $tr=substr ($seq, $s-1, $e-$s+1); 
    push (@transmembrane, $tr);
```

Next the statement `print @transmembrane;` is in the scope of the `while` block, so will be output after every line is read from `P30988.txt`. It needs to be moved out of the `while` block scope.

The next very fundamental issue is you are running the `substr` statement against the `$seq` variable before it has been populated. Looking at `P30988.txt`, I see that the `FT TRANSMEM` lines come *before* the sequence data. The `$seq` variable will not have been populated when you run the `substr` statement.

That means to need to store the `FT TRANSMEM` offsets and run the `substr` commands once the while loop terminates.

Here is a rewrite that does that (note I've commented out the printing of `$seq`)

```
open (IN,'P30988.txt');
while (<IN>) {
    if($_=~ m/^ID/) {
        print $_ ; }
    if($_=~ m/^AC/){
        print $_ ; }
    #if ($_=~ m/^SQ/){
        #print $_; }
    if ($_=~ m/^\s+(.+)/) { 
        $seq.=$1;                        #Here I match ONLY the sequence
        $seq=~s/\s//g; 
        #print $seq;       #Here I removed spaces from the sequence
     } 
    
    
    if($_=~ m/^FT\s+TRANSMEM\s+(\d+)\.\.(\d+)/){  
        $s = $1; 
        $e = $2;

        # store the offset & length for later
        push @transmembrane, [ $s-1, $e-$s+1 ];
    } 

}

for my $item (@transmembrane)
{
    my ($from, $len) = @$item;
    print substr($seq, $from, $len) . "\n";
}
```

I get this when I run the modified code

```
ID   CALCR_HUMAN             Reviewed;         474 AA.
AC   P30988; A0A0C4DG16; A4D1G6; F5H605; O14585; Q13941; Q5ZGL8; Q659U6; Q6DJU8;
AC   Q6T712;
IVGHSLSIFTLVISLGIFVFF
MFLTYILNSMIIIIHLVEVVP
YFWMLCEGIYLHTLIVVAVFT
LRWYYLLGWGFPLVPTTIHAI
LLYIIHGPVMAALVVNFFFLL
AVKATMILVPLLGIQFVVFPW
YVMHSLIHFQGFFVATIYCFC
```